# Lottie flutter takes some time to show, but the json has just 13kb

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

So, as the title says, I'm using Lottie package and I'm getting some strange behaviour, see below:

[image]

As the gif shows, the widget loads (the text appears in the center of the screen, but not the animation) and after a while, the animation loads.

Here is the code for this widget that I've created:

```
class AnimatedLoadingCommonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedLoadingCommonWidget({
    super.key,
    this.loadingMessages,
    this.singleMessage,
    this.shouldAnimationAdapts = false,
  });

  final List<String>? loadingMessages;
  final List<TextSpan>? singleMessage;
  final bool shouldAnimationAdapts;

  @override
  State<AnimatedLoadingCommonWidget> createState() =>
      _AnimatedLoadingCommonWidgetState();
}

class _AnimatedLoadingCommonWidgetState
    extends State<AnimatedLoadingCommonWidget> {
  ValueNotifier<String> currentMessage = ValueNotifier('');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    assert(widget.loadingMessages != null || widget.singleMessage != null);

    if (widget.loadingMessages != null) {
      int currentMessageIndex = 1;

      currentMessage.value = widget.loadingMessages![0];

      // this code runs after every 2.2 seconds.
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2, milliseconds: 200), (_) {
        currentMessage.value = widget.loadingMessages![currentMessageIndex];
        if (currentMessageIndex + 1 == widget.loadingMessages!.length) {
          currentMessageIndex = 0;
        } else {
          currentMessageIndex++;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          widget.shouldAnimationAdapts
              ? Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Lottie.asset(
                        'assets/animations/json.zip',
                        animate: true,
                        frameRate: FrameRate.max
                      ),
                      Image.asset('assets/images/shape.png'),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : Stack(
                  children: [
                    Lottie.asset(
                      'assets/animations/json.zip',
                      animate: true,
                      frameRate: FrameRate.max
                    ),
                    Image.asset('assets/images/shape.png'),
                  ],
                ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 65,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                if (widget.loadingMessages != null)
                  ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: currentMessage,
                    builder: (context, message, child) => Text(
                      message,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                if (widget.singleMessage != null)
                  RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      ),
                      children: widget.singleMessage,
                    ),
                  ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Por favor, aguarde',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: greyScale07,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is supposed to be like this, or I got something wrong?

PS. I already test using the default frame rate.

Edit:
This only happens in this particular case. (it's the first time that I have this loading shown). In other cenarios, post first loading, the animation displays correctly.

Comment: What a good coincidence. I thought about it yesterday. I think it could solve a state management method. Because the gif is loaded from web service by internet and it takes time. We could use it with a progress circle so it shows when it is fetching.

Comment: My problem is that my animation is in my assets and not from web service :/